# I want to validate after submission of the form but it also validate before submission of the form using jquery in drupal forms

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, drupal

In contact form having one radio button with two value email and phone I want to validate after submission of the form but it also validate before submission of the form using jquery in drupal forms..
In my form when i click email it show one email text field with error and hide phone text field similary i choose phone it show both email and phone text field but for phone text field only it shows error for email field it doesnot show error now i completed this work whats my prblm is before clicking submit button i change email and phone value it shows the error but i want to show the error after submitting the form only..

Comment: can show your code? what you have done already... Karthika

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8wc8an4q/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you really insist on using jquery independently then you should put it in a function and call it with an onclick/onchange attribute:

```
$form['wayToContact'] = array(
       '#type' => 'radios',
       '#validated' => TRUE,
       '#title' => t('Best way to contact'),
       '#default_value' => 'Email',
       '#options' => array('Email' => $this->t('Email'), 'Phone' => $this->t('Phone')),
       '#attributes' => array(
            'class' => array('required')
            'onchange' => 'yourFunction(this)',
            'onclick' => 'yourFunction(this)'
       )
     );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the #states property on your field to do what you are asking. You can add multiple validations and it will create all the jquery for you.

e.g.:

```
// Show the email field when email selected for radiofld
$form['email'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Email'),
  '#states' => array(
    'visible' => array(
      array(
        ':input[name="radiofld"]' => array('value' => 'email'),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);

// Show error message for phone field
$form['phoneerr'] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => 'No Phone selected',
  '#states' => array(
    'visible' => array(
      array(
        ':input[name="radiofld"]' => array('value' => 'email'),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);  

// Show the phone field when phone selected for radiofld
$form['phone'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Phone'),
  '#states' => array(
    'visible' => array(
      array(
        ':input[name="radiofld"]' => array('value' => 'phone'),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);

// Show error message for email field
$form['emailerr'] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => 'No Email selected',
  '#states' => array(
    'visible' => array(
      array(
        ':input[name="radiofld"]' => array('value' => 'phone'),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thank you Angus Walker but i want to vaidate it using jquery...Can you help for it.

Comment: Why do you want to write the jquery yourself?
In the above example Drupal uses jquery and writes it for you!